# No puedo guardar un producto en el localstorage luego de actualizar la pagina

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

Siguiendo un tutorial de angular, llegue a un punto, de querer agregar más productos luego de hacer un refrescar la página. La información se guarda en el **localStorage**. Pero luego de querer guardar más productos, me sale el siguiente error.

```
ERROR TypeError: this.orderService.order.addProductOrder is not a function
    at ProductsComponent.addProduct
```

[image: Error]

Cuando presiono un botón para agregar, llamo el siguiente método que esta en el fichero **Products.components.ts**

```
addProduct(product: Products){
    this.orderService.order.addProductOrder(product)
    this.orderService.saveLastOrder()
  }
```

Y que a su vez llama al método que está en el fichero **IOrders.ts**

```
import { OrderDetail } from "./IOrderDetail";
import { Products } from "./IProducts";

export interface IOrders{
    ClientId: number
    ClientName: string
    Id:number
    DateOrder: Date
}

export class Orders implements IOrders{
    
    ClientId!: number;
    ClientName!: string;
    Id!: number;
    DateOrder!: Date
    Detail!: Array<OrderDetail>;

    constructor(){
        this.Detail = new Array<OrderDetail>();
    }

    addProductOrder(product: Products){

        let orderDetail: OrderDetail = new OrderDetail()        

        orderDetail.Stock = 1
        orderDetail.ProductName = `${product.Name} ${product.Brand}`
        orderDetail.Price = product.Price
        orderDetail.ProductId = product.Id

        let exists: number = this.Detail.filter(prod => prod.ProductId === product.Id).length

        if(exists > 0){
            let index: number = this.Detail.findIndex(prod => prod.ProductId === product.Id)
            this.Detail[index].Stock++
        }else{
            this.Detail.push(orderDetail);
        }   
    
    }
}
```

El servicio se llama desde el siguiente fichero **AddProduct.Service.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Orders } from '../Models/IOrders';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})

export class S_OrdersService {  
  
  order: Orders = new Orders();

  constructor() { 
    this.order.addProductOrder
    this.order = this.localOrder
  }  

  get countOrders() {

    let localOrders: Orders[] = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("Orders")!) 
    if(localOrders === null){
      return 0
    }else{
      return localOrders.length
    }   
    
  }

  saveLastOrder(){
    localStorage.setItem("lastOrder", JSON.stringify(this.order))
  }

  get localOrder(): Orders{

    let orderInLocal: Orders = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("lastOrder")!)
    if(orderInLocal === null){
      return new Orders
    }
    return orderInLocal
  }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como ya te mencionaron, el serializador del objeto window.JSON no tiene en cuenta a funciones, solamente trabaja con tipos de datos primitivos y `undefined` y `null`. Puedes hacer lo que te sugiere @PabloLozano o puedes usar un serializador personalizado; por ejemplo [class-transformer](https://github.com/typestack/class-transformer).

**BaseModel**

```
import { classToPlain, plainToClass } from "class-transformer";

export class BaseModel {
    static fromJson<T extends BaseModel>(json: Record<string, any>): T {
        return plainToClass(this, json) as T;
    }

    toJson(): Record<string, any> {
        return classToPlain(this);
    }
}
```

Luego, extienda su clase `Orders` de `BaseModel`:

```
export class Orders extends BaseModel implements IOrders {
   ...
}
```

Por último, modifique el getter `localOrder`:

> **Nota**: Es importante que su clase `Orders` tenga datos primitivos solamente para que puedan ser asignados a la instancia creada por el serializador; de lo contrario se perderán.

```
get localOrder(): Orders{
    let orderInLocal: Record<string, any> | null = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("lastOrder")!)
    if(orderInLocal === null){
      return new Orders()
    }
    return Orders.fromJson<Orders>(orderInLocal)
}
```

Comment: Funciona perfecto, muy interesante lo del serializador. Buscando en otros problemas parecidos, veía que algunos recomendaban dicho repositorio como una ayuda para solucionar.

Answer (score 5):

[JSON](https://www.json.org/json-en.html) no soporta funciones, sólo:

```
object
array
string
number
"true"
"false"
"null"
```

La clase que creaste [es básicamente una función](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes)

> Classes are in fact "special functions"

Por lo tanto no pueden ser **de-serializadas** que es lo que ocurre cuando almacenas algo en el storage del navegador mediante un proceso de serialización (`JSON.stringify`) y luego tratas de revertir el proceso mediante `JSON.parse`

La solución es modificar la clase o añadir un método estático que te permita crear una instancia a partir de un objeto plano. En tu caso especifico podría ser:

```javascript
    constructor(order?: any) {
        if (order) {
            this.ClientId = order.ClientId;
            this.ClientName = order.ClientName;
            this.Id = order.Id;
            this.DateOrder = order.DateOrder;
            this.Detail = order.Detail;
        } else {
            this.Detail = new Array<OrderDetail>();
        }        
    }
```

También deberías considerar implementar una interfaz separada de la clase para representar ese objeto plano que no tiene métodos y es el parámetro del constructor.

Comment: Gracias maestro, y cómo sería el caso de la modificación de la clase?

Comment: @PedroMiguelPimientaMorales el ejemplo de código que le puse es la parte del constructor modificada, solo tiene que reemplazar el constructor de la clase `Orders` y asegurarse que siempre se llama `new Orders(jsonItem)` cada vez que intente reconstruir el objeto del storage

Comment: Lo vi, pensé que hablabas de otro ejemplo, gracias

Comment: Sigue saliendo el mismo error

Answer (score 1):

Al guardar/obtener un objeto del localStorage necesitas usar JSON.stringify/JSON.parse. Esto significa que si el objeto tenía métodos, éstos se han perdido:

```js
const order = {
  id: '123',
  metodo: function () {
    return 'El id es ' + this.id;
  }
};

console.log(order.metodo());

let texto = JSON.stringify(order);
console.log('El objeto tiene las propiedades', Object.keys(order));
console.log('El JSON resultante:', texto);
```

Así que si quieres mantener los métodos, puedes usar un constructor que rellene los campos, para seguir trabajando con un objeto de la clase requerida:

```js
class Order {

  constructor(data) {
    this.id = data?.id;
    this.name = data?.name;
  }
  
  method() {
    return `Orden ${this.id}-${this.name}`;
  }
}

const order = new Order(); // creamos el objeto de clase Order
order.id = '123';
order.name = 'Orden 1';

console.log(order.method()); //funcionan sus métodos

let texto = JSON.stringify(order); //lo pasamos a JSON, hemos perdido el método!
console.log('El JSON resultante:', texto);
let copiaObtenida = JSON.parse(texto); //creamos el objeto con los datos, 
console.log('el método es', copiaObtenida.method); //no tenemos el método
console.log('Es su clase Order?', copiaObtenida instanceof Order);
const order2 = new Order(copiaObtenida);

console.log('Es AHORA su clase Order?', order2 instanceof Order);
console.log(order2.method());
```

Comment: Buena respuesta, pude comprender ya como tal proceso que ocurre cuando se hace  a texto y se pretende serializar este texto esperando que retorne como estaba en un principio.